# A noon cannon with two lenses

Tags: optics, astronomy, geometry, lenses

A noon cannon usually has a single convex lens which focuses sunlight onto a fuse.  The cannon contains gunpowder.  The fuse ignites and the gun discharges at noon.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial_cannon

A query has arisen about a noon cannon with TWO lenses -- what is the benefit of having two lenses?  Does it provide more heat to ignite the fuse?  The noon cannon with two lenses might be larger than usual, therefore needing a lens with a longer focal length.  Images below.

[image: noon cannon with two lenses]

[image: close-up of noon cannon with two lenses]

Thank you for any suggestions.  I know quite a lot about sundials but I am not a physicist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually it is the same. But you can make a better lens with multiple elements.

The lens makes a small image of the Sun. A strong lens (short focal length) makes a smaller image.

One way to make a short focal length is to make highly curved surfaces. But that create worse spherical aberration, and a blurry image.

Another way is to use two lenses with more gentle curvature.